# error on starting OpenSIPS server( PID file )

Tags: opensips

I'm using opensips and I did the configuration exactly like the tutorial but when I run the command that start opensips there is an error
My PID file doesn't exist how to create it? normally the PID file is created automatically

root@ubuntu:/var/run/opensips# sudo opensipsctl start

INFO: Starting OpenSIPS :

**ERROR:**

> PID file /var/run/opensips/opensips.pid does not exist -- OpenSIPS
>   start failed

Answer (score 0):

check /var/log/syslog becouse problem not in PID file.

opensips check if it started by checking if PID file exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reasons may cause opensips fail to start step by step :

**1. Check opensips for script errors**

You can see it in logs as Erewin said or try to start opensips in debug mode:

```
sudo opensips -DEddd
```

If you see any errors - fix it

**2. Check run directory exists and has right permissions**

Here is mine

```
ls -ald /var/run/opensips
drwxr-xr-x. 2 opensips opensips 40 Jan  9 12:51 /var/run/opensips
```

**3. Check pid file settings in opensipsctlrc**

It should be

```
PID_FILE=/var/run/opensips/opensips.pid
```

Most probably in your case the opensips can't start because of errors (ex. 1) but lets leave other reasons here too in case some one else stuck with the same problem.